# Hololens 2/Unity Error: A material (Instance)(Instance)... which is already instanced was instanced multiple times

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I have instanced a simple scrolling menu prefab in my scene (prefab provided by MRTK2 with just one menu option available).  I have a button in the scene that when clicked will either `SetActive(true)` or `SetActive(false)` on this menu to show/hide it.  When the menu is `SetActive(false)` and then `SetActive(true)` it provides the sequence of errors depicted in the picture below.  I've found this [thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1308224/mesh-filter-and-mesh-renderer-why-2-components.html) that may be related but ultimately I don't know what this error means or how to fix it.

[image]

It seems that all of these errors are w.r.t. components on objects in the menu that existed from the prefab, so I'm confused as to why these errors are happening.  I tried to replace the components with their MRTK counterparts as I was reading somewhere that MRTK versions of shaders, etc. are more efficient and was hoping that maybe they would simply solve the issue (they haven't).

For example, it seems that the error regarding `MRTK_PressableInteractablesButtonBox (Instance) (Instance)` is the shader on the `FrontPlate` of the button in the menu option.

[image]
[image]

Similarly, the error regarding `sequisb SDF Material (Instance) (Instance)` is the `FontAsset` on the `TextMeshPro` under the menu option's `IconAndText` object.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the version of MRTK package you are using? Did you modify the **MaterialInstance** script or call it in your custom script?
By default, **SetActive()** doesn't cause the material to be instantiated repeatedly. I have tested the **Demo-ScrollingObjectCollection** from **MRTK Examples** package, and cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: Can you show the code of `MaterialInstance`? Also why do you have a prefab overwrite removing this component and then adding it again? I would rather revert these two and stick to the original instance ;)

Comment: FWIW, I don't remember ever modifying the `MaterialInstance` script and I don't think it had been changed when I debugged it, but I was able to get things working...see my answer to this post.  Thanks for both of your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, my solution doesn't provide an explanation as to what caused my original error.  However, I was able to get everything working by simply scrapping the old menu and recreating from the same prefab.  I guess cross-wiring must have occurred at some point that I was unable to trace down.  Ultimately, all I needed was a scrollable menu with a click event listener and buttons with custom meshes...all of which seem to be working fine now.

Thanks to @Zuocheng Wang and @derHugo for pointing me in the right direction (i.e. that things "should" work essentially out-of-box for the desired functionality).